# Play framework cannot find assets

Tags: playframework, assets

There are several questions related to this. But I'm only using the recommended defaults. Here is my `conf/routes`:

```
GET     /assets/*file  controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Running `sbt stage` followed by `./target/universal/stage/bin/myapp`, I get a 404 for anything that I have under `public`.

Those CSS and Javascript files are not under `./target/universal/stage/bin/myapp`, though I don't know whether they should be. Another webserver (caddy) is forwarding 443 to 9000. I can view an index.html page (which correctly queries a database).

Caddy does proxy all of the requests correctly. All GET requests to `/public/xxx` and `/assets/yyy` result in 404s. I'm using play 2.5.10.

```
ls
app  build.sbt  conf  project  public  README.md  target
```

Comment: Do you see an assets jar (something like `target/my-first-app-1.0.0-assets.jar`)? What urls are returning 404? Which version of Play are you using? Can you confirm that Caddy is correctly proxying the request to your Play application?

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify. There is no target/my-first-app-1.0.0-assets.jar.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible test case for this problem?